# Getting Windows Server 2012 R2 to see HP Storage Works SATA Array on a HP Proliant DL585 G2

Tags: windows-server-2012, hp-storageworks

I have installed Windows Server 2012 R2 on a HP Proliant DL585 G2 Server and everything seems to be loaded fine except the external HP Storageworks SAS SCSI Array.

On HP's website they have drivers for windows server 2008 R2 and I was hoping that those drivers would work for Server 2012 R2.  No Luck.

The driver installation will not even let me try to install, as it is not for the correct operating system.  Is there a way I can bypass this?

I can extract the files and they are:
.LogFiles
cp020547.xml
cpqsetup.exe
generic.dll
hpcisss2.cat
hpcisss2.sys
hpcissx2.inf
install.xml

Thanks,

Comment: have you tried choosing "update drivers" from the device properties within the Windows device manager and pointing to the directory containing the extracted .sys / .inf files? The installer might prevent you from running it on a different OS, but the drivers may be working nonetheless.

Comment: Dunno what the what you're using but sometimes the backup software has its own drivers, like BackupExec, perhaps you could give that a try?